# Are platyhellmintes and annelids segmented?

Tags: zoology, taxonomy, classification, annelida

Are the organisms of platyhelminthes unsegmented worms or segment? And what about those belonging to annelida?

I guess Platyhelminthes are unsegmented and annelida are segmented but i am not sure about it?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. A title should be a short version of the content and not just the field of interest. You should use the tags to indicate the field of interest. Also we expect from an OP some effort to answer its own question. Your question is answered by the first sentences of the respective wikipedia articles. I edited your question. Feel free to roll back if you don't like the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the first sentences from the wikipedia articles for [platyheminthes](http://The%20flatworms,%20or%20Platyhelminthes,%20Plathelminthes,%20or%20platyhelminths%20(from%20the%20Greek%20%CF%80%CE%BB%CE%B1%CF%84%CF%8D,%20platy,%20meaning%20%22flat%22%20and%20%E1%BC%95%CE%BB%CE%BC%CE%B9%CE%BD%CF%82%20(root:%20%E1%BC%91%CE%BB%CE%BC%CE%B9%CE%BD%CE%B8-),%20helminth-,%20meaning%20%22worm%22)[2]%20are%20a%20phylum%20of%20relatively%20simple%20bilaterian,%20unsegmented,%20soft-bodied%20invertebrates.) and [annelids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annelid):

> The **flatworms**, or Platyhelminthes, Plathelminthes, or platyhelminths (from the Greek πλατύ, platy, meaning "flat" and ἕλμινς (root: ἑλμινθ-), helminth-, meaning "worm")[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annelid) are a phylum of relatively simple bilaterian, **unsegmented**, soft-bodied invertebrates.
>
> The **annelids** (Annelida, from Latin anellus, "little ring"),[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annelid)[n 1] also known as the ringed worms or **segmented** worms, are a large phylum, with over 17,000 extant species including ragworms, earthworms, and leeches.